# SSRS - Checking whether the data is null

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I've the following expression in my report.

```
=FormatNumber(MAX(Fields!Reading.Value, "CellReading_Reading"),3)
```

Now when the dataset is empty 'Fields!Reading.Value' becomes empty and finding their maximum is invalid. How can i check if the entire column is empty?

I tried the following with no luck.

```
=iif(IsNothing(Fields!.Reading.Value),"",FormatNumber(MAX(Fields!Reading.Value, "CellReading_Reading"),3))
```

But still i'm getting #Error in the report. I also checked out [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835954/sql-2005-reporting-services-if-check-for-null) and was not able to get a clue from it. I want to handle it in the report level.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

try like this

```
= IIF( MAX( iif( IsNothing(Fields!.Reading.Value ), -1, Fields!.Reading.Value ) ) = -1, "",  FormatNumber(  MAX( iif( IsNothing(Fields!.Reading.Value ), -1, Fields!.Reading.Value ), "CellReading_Reading"),3)) )
```

Answer (score 6):

Or in your SQL query wrap that field with IsNull or Coalesce (SQL Server).

Either way works, I like to put that logic in the query so the report has to do less.